# The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, smtp

I inherited a .NET 3.5 MVC (looks like MVC version 1) site that I migrated to a different server. I installed the SMTP feature (IIS 7), as well as started the virtual server in IIS 6. Back in IIS 7, I made sure the SMTP email setting was delivering to localhost, and I checked on ports on the firewall. Still getting this message. And since I've never worked with MVC before, I can't locate the code that is supposed to send this mail. I have no idea where to look.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
HttpException (0x80004005): The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid.
]
   System.Web.Mail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args) +99
   System.Web.Mail.CdoSysHelper.Send(MailMessage message) +1738
   System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(MailMessage message) +273
   IPS.Controllers.AccountController.OnAfterResetPassword(String email, String userName, String newPassword) in B:\IPS\Controllers\AccountController.cs:207
   IPS.Controllers.AccountController.ForgotPassword(String userName) in B:\IPS\Controllers\AccountController.cs:192
   lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +85
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__7() +53
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +258
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__9() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +193
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +123
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +144
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +7
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Okay, found the controller code:

```
[NonAction]
protected virtual void OnAfterResetPAssword(string email, string userName, string newPassword)
{
     System.Web.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
     mail.To = email;
     mail.From = "admin@thisserver.com";
     mail.Subject = "New Password";
     mail.Body = "Here is your new password";

     System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(mail).
}
```

I changed it to:

```
[NonAction]
protected virtual void OnAfterResetPAssword(string email, string userName, string newPassword)
{
     System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
     mail.To.Add(email);
     mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("admin@thisserver.com");
     mail.Subject = "New Password";
     mail.Body = "Here is your new password";

     System.Net.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(mail).
}
```

And my web.config:

```
<system.net>
   <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
         <network host="<FULL HOST IP ADDRESS>" port="25" userName="" password="" />
      </smtp>
   </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Running the site with those changes rendered the EXACT same stack trace... even the parts where it says

> System.Web.Mail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args) +99
>   System.Web.Mail.CdoSysHelper.Send(MailMessage message) +1738
>   System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(MailMessage message) +273

Isnt it weird that it still says System.Web.Mail??? I'm not sure how MVC works. Do I have to recompile or anything like that? I even tested the SMTP server on port 25 with the standard telnet request and it works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you'll need to rebuild the project, but you're on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnAfterResetPassword` method/action in your `AccountController` is using the deprecated `System.Web.Mail` namespace. You can't configure this to use the mail settings in `system.net/mailSettings/smtp` in your `web.config` file as you would in `System.Net.Mail`, it isn't aware of them.

If you have the source code then update to use `System.Net.Mail` instead:

> [System.Net.Mail Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx)
>   [System.Net.Mail FAQ](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq.aspx)

If you can't do this then check the following:

- The `System.Web.Mail` `SmtpMail.SmtpServer` property is either not set and the local SMTP service isn't running
- `SmtpMail.SmtpServer` property is set but the server can't access the SMTP server
- It's possible that the worker process account (if you're not using impersonation) doesn't have permission to access the SMTP service

Comment: I have to check and see if I have the source code for this. I will revisit it tonight when I get home and come back here to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's in the Account controller. FWIW, I think System.Net.Smtp is the "right" way to do it now (I think System.Web.Mail is deprecated).  You might want to check out the Email Sender project on codeplex, also: http://emailsender.codeplex.com/, it makes things simpler still.